# Counting objects in specific positions on an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

Before diving in the coding part of my question, I have to write an introduction to give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve. Also keep in mind that I have a very weak coding background, and that this is my first Python project.

I am working on a project involving microfluidics (µflu) and human cell imaging. The broad idea of the project is to trap single cells at specific places in microfluidic devices to allow for single cell imaging *via* innovative methods. To assess the efficiency of my microfluidic devices, I have access to a [plate imager](https://www.biotek.com/products/imaging-microscopy-cell-imaging-multi-mode-readers/cytation-5-cell-imaging-multi-mode-reader/). This allows me to capture images of the whole µflu device (a zone of about 3x2 cm²) with the cells (which are marked by fluorescence) in it. The obtained .tif images are very large (around 20000x10000 px) and weigh around 500 mB each. Here is an example image (screenshot of the actual image) :

[image]

Th µflu device aims at immobilizing single cells on a regularly spaced grid (which is not really visible on the images), which you can see on some parts of the previous image, or on this close-up view :

[image]

However, things are not perfect and as you saw on the first image, a lot of fluorescent signal is leaking in the µflu channels, clogging can happen, etc...

So, here is what I am trying to write code for :

1. Cleaning the image : removing parasite fluorescent signal
2. Counting all the cells on the cleaned image
3. Counting only the cells that are on the designed grid
4. Discriminating between single cells and cells agglomerates (which you can see one of in the second image)

Regarding the first objective, I managed to obtain this image from the first one (the image is NOT pitch black, the cells are juste really small compared to the whole image) :

[image]

Here is the code I wrote for this :

```
imgArray = imageio.imread(filename)   #Loading the image

#Converting the image from 16bit to 8bit array
imgConvertedArray = (imgArray >> 8).astype('uint8') #Actual conversion

#Thresholding the array and filling small holes
imgThresholdedArray = (imgConvertedArray == 255) * imgConvertedArray   #Actual thresholding (setting all values < 250 to 0)
imgThresholdedArray = morphology.remove_small_holes(imgThresholdedArray, 100, 1)
imgThresholdedArray = imgThresholdedArray.astype('uint8')

#Removing objects too small or too big for a cell from thresholded image
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(imgThresholdedArray, connectivity=4)   #Find all the connected components
sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1
min_size = 10   #Minimum size of component to keep
max_size = 300   #Maximum size of component to keep
imgThresholdedArrayCleaned = numpy.zeros((output.shape))   #Creating an array with the same size as the array to filter
for i in range(0, nb_components):   #Keeping only the components with good size
    if sizes[i] >= min_size and sizes[i] <= max_size:
        imgThresholdedArrayCleaned[output == i + 1] = 255
imgThresholdedArrayCleaned = cv2.normalize(imgThresholdedArrayCleaned, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)   #Normalizing the result
```

Now, the results I obtain is not perfect, as there is still some "parasite" signal, and I might have lost some actual cells in the process. Also, the code is slow (about 5 minutes to run on a single image), but this might simply be due to the size of the images.

Here are my questions :

- how should I go about improving my image "cleaning" code ? Would a "contour finding" method provide better results ?
- I have no idea how to approach counting the cells that are on the grid. Any idea ?

I will answer questions or provide more images if needed. Thank you.

EDIT 1 - Here is a highlight of the difference between the cells (in green) and the parasitic signal left after I already "cleaned" the image (in red) :

[image]

Comment: For those of us who don't know a cell from a parasite, maybe you could add a further image with the things you do want circled in, say, Green and the things you don't want circled in, say, Red? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited the question with an additional image.